# Completing a very difficult triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I have an isosceles triangle with the two equal sides of length 'c', and the bottom of length 'a'. Both base angles of the triangle have measures of 'a', in degrees. For example, if 'a' were 50, both these angles would be 50 degrees. What I'm attempting to do is find the missing angle, 'c'. It's measurement in degrees is equal to that of both of the sides of length 'c', much the same way as 'a'. This is what I have so far: 2(a * sin(a)) + a = The perimeter. Also, a * sin(a) / 2 = c. However, this is as far as I can get, as I have no idea what the perimeter is. Does anyone know how to solve a problem like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Both base angles of the triangle have measures of 'a' in degrees."?

Comment: Judging by your question, $d=a\cos(a)/2$

Comment: The way it's phrased, is the measure of the angles (in degrees) equal to the length of the base (in length units)?  If that's what you're saying, isn't the missing angle just $180 - 2a$?

Comment: Note that choosing the angles of an isosceles triangle identifies it up to similarity. There will be one amongst the family of similar triangles which has a base of a given fixed length. Also given $a$ the whole triangle is known since you have the length of the base and the two base angles - you can use the sine rule to solve for $d$.

Comment: @MartianInvader, you are correct. In degrees, it is equal to the length of the base in units. However, I would like to find an exact measurement for it, not just 180 - 2a. I think you would need to solve for 'a' if you wanted to find the missing angle. I admit, I'm not even sure it's possible. However, I'm not very good with trigonometry, so I figured there might be a chance in solving it using so method that I don't know of.

Comment: Wouldn't the cosine rule work here ?: $a=\sqrt{d^2+d^2-2\cdot d \cdot d \cdot \cos c}$

Comment: @recursiverecursion I don't think you've supplied enough data to get an answer that's just a number.  You could have an almost-flat triangle with two 1-degree angles and a length 1 base, or you could have a very tall triangle with two 89-degree angles and a length 89 base.  The third angle will be 178 degrees in the former and 2 degrees in the latter.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'm sorry, I accidentally did not post enough information. As you see, I just edited it so that d is equal to c.

Comment: One solution is a 60-60-60 triangle

Comment: Wow, all of your answers have been great. This is my first time getting a question answered without any answer, only comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sine rule, we get

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{\sin c^\circ} =& \frac{c}{\sin a^\circ}\\
a\sin a^{\circ} = &c\sin c^\circ\\
a\sin a^{\circ} =& (180-2a) \sin 2a^\circ\\
a\sin a^{\circ} =&2(180-2a)\sin a^\circ \cos a^\circ\\
a =& 2(180-2a)\cos a^\circ\\
\frac1{\cos a^\circ} =& \frac{360}a-4
\end{align*}$$

For the range of $a\in(0,90)$, the left hand side $\sec a$ is increasing, and the right hand side is decreasing. So the equilateral triangle is the only answer.

Comment: thank you very much! I was going to ask for a proof of this, but you read my mind!